# Using Thread.Sleep() in Dispatcher.BeginInvoke's delegate

Tags: wpf, multithreading

I am looking for the way to sleep the dispatcher thread but didn't found any way. I know there is 'this.Dispatcher.Thread' but I don't think i.e what I am looking for because it doesn't have sleep().

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                                        //Thread.Sleep         

            }));
```

Comment: Just to make sure, are you aware that "sleeping the dispatcher thread" will freeze the UI ?

Comment: Yup. I asked for alternate way..to hold the execution inside delegate for a particular time span.

Comment: This is almost certainly the wrong solution to whatever problem you are trying to solve.  `Thread.Sleep` is almost always undesirable, as is blocking the UI thread.

Comment: @MikeStrobel that is what I am looking for the solution, to hold the execution in delegate without impacting the main thread

Comment: The UI thread is the main thread... Why not just do the execution on the main thread instead of in a new Thread?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Thread.Sleep` it sleeps the current thread, so when you do the following:

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Thread.Sleep(1000)));
```

It will sleep and freeze the UI thread for 1 second.

I strongly advise against this, however it should answer your question.

Comment: What exactly is discussed in the comments? My answer is not and neither is my opinion.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? My answer is a perfectly valid answer for the question.